# xcode - add *.ogg files to Sandbox

Tags: ios, xcode, sandbox, ogg

I want to add to my project an *.ogg file. I need XCode to place it somewhere in Sandbox. If I drag and drop, it won't work. If I do the same with a mp3 file, it works. Any idea how can i get to have that ogg file in Sandbox?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody told me the solution. I had to add the file mannualy from Project / Buid Phases / Copy Bundle Resources and it worked.